# Can't save entity with auto-join: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

Tags: entity-framework, self-join

I have an entity which has a relation to itself (auto-join), implementing a typical hierarchical relation. It has an `Id` and a `ParentId` (both of type int). The Id is an identity field in the table, so its value is geenrated on saving, and this is correctly reflected in the EF model.

When I try to save a new entity (with `Add` + `SaveChanges`) with `ParentId` = 0, EF shows this error:

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
```

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF has an strange behaviour in this case: obviously, as it's a new entity, and the `Id` will be generated buythe db, it isn't initialized and has its default value of 0.

When EF tries to determine how to save this entity, it finds that its `Id` and its `ParentId` are equal (both are equal to zero). This makes EF find a circular reference of the entity with itself, and thus the error.

To solve the problem you simply have to break the circular reference. As the value of the `Id` will eventually be generated by the database, it doesn't matter which value it has when it's added to the context for saving. So, you simply have to give the `Id` a value other than zero, and it works like a charm.

In this partiuclar case, I'm handling legacy code, and this is the only solution. But, for a new application, see the recommendations below.

**Avoiding this problem by design**

The simplest solution for this problem, it's to avoid having an entity with Id = 0. In this way, there will be no accidental "circular reference".

If you see hvd's comments, you'll find that there is a second problem: you can't insert the first row using your EF code, because the `Id` and the `ParentId` would have to be the same, and, as stated, this will make EF fail. To solve this problem you have two options:

1. Change the design so that `ParentId` can be null (make it `int?`). In this way, you can insert the first row with a null value in `ParentId`
2. Execute a direct `INSERT INTO` sentence for the first insertion (in SSMS, using ADO.NET, executing the query directly from the context...). If you do so, the insertion will be handled directly by the DB, and there will be no problem.

*NOTE 1:* In both cases, inserting a row related to itself is impossible through EF.

*NOTE 2:* Depending on the number of rows in the table, making the parent id nullable can degrade query performance, and take up more disk space: an `INT NOT NULL` column takes up less space, and gives better performance on indexing than an `INT NULL` column. If this is a concern, take the 2nd solution.

Comment: Agreed on your description of what happens and why that doesn't work, but I'd take the other route for solving the problem: I'd give `ParentId` a value different from zero. Specifically, I'd make `ParentId` of type `int?` and give it `null` as its value.

Comment: I prefer to avoid nulls because of performance. It would be cleaner to change the entity with Id = 0 to have a different Id, so there are no circular references. (In fact, the entity with Id = 0 is the root of the hierarchy). It's no longer possible because tehre are lots of related logic and data using this id. I'm upgrading my answer to reflect this idea.

Comment: "I prefer to avoid nulls because of performance." - Huh? In what way do nulls cause any performance problems? Actually, if you don't make `ParentId` nullable, you've got a scenario that EF only partially supports. You would not be able to add any entities unless you already have some. That may be enough for your needs, but it wouldn't help someone else who encounters this problem and finds your question and answer.

Comment: I refer to DB performance. It's much more efficient to store and index and query an int than a nullable int on the DB side. But there is a more important reason: the parent id must be 0, because 0 is the value of the parent node... and, I would have to change this value in the DB (in the entity's table, and related tables) and the semantics in the legacy code. I'll update my answer with an explanation of the problem you're exposing.